# WPF distortion in TextBlock elements

Tags: wpf, xaml, text-rendering

See http://inky.ws/g/21s for screencaps of the text rendering distortion.

I apply this style to get a glow effect:

```
<Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="GlowBright"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource ToolTipBase}">
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="1" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="7"
                              Color="White"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!-- Expander headers, Group box headers, Check box headers, Labels -->
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlowBright}"/>
```

Unfortunately, it's making certain element rendering glitchy. The glitches change or disappear when I resize the window. So... how to avoid the glitches?

---

Edit - doing this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource GlowBright}">
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Ideal"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextHintingMode" Value="Fixed"/>
    <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextRenderingMode" Value="ClearType"/>
</Style>
```

does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you're running into issues with your video card drivers, as the DropShadowEffect is accomplished with a pixel shader (compiles into a special routine that runs on the video card.)  It's not at all uncommon for older drivers to introduce visual defects when using shaders.  If this is only occurring on your machine, this is likely the cause.

Comment: This must be it, because I can't explain it any other way... crappy deal.

Comment: Updating the drivers fixed the problem! INTERNET BEWARE! If you have the Intel HD Graphics 3000, update the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this attach property **TextOptions.TextFormattingMode**. More can be found through [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textoptions.textformattingmode.aspx)

```
<TextBox TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" FontSize="15">HELLO WORLD</TextBox>
```

*

### *Guidelines for this property*

**Scenarios Recommended Mode**

**Large Text (15pt+)** = *Ideal \ Display (users preference)*

**Transformed Text** = *Ideal*

**Zoomed Text** = *Ideal*

**Design Scenarios** = *Ideal*

**Small Text** = *Display*

Comment: Have you tried using other machine if it still has that glitch?

Comment: Don't have access to any other machines, but I don't see how it would be machine-specific.